# How do I get output to consolidate from 2 lines to 1 line?

Tags: teradata

How can I change the way my output comes back to get it all on one line? Right now if has 2 lines. RA equals 1KK8888 in both, and the fee in one line and the Rate in the secound line.

```
select  

                ,FRP.rent_doc_cd as Contract
                ,case when charge.charge_id = 7213 then charge.chg_amt else 0 end as FEE
                ,case when charge.charge_id = 7220 then charge.chg_amt  else 0 end as Rate


    FROM intgX.RENTAL_Tbl FRP                                                                 
    left join intgX.RENTAL_CHG charge  on FRP.renalt_document = charge.rental_document and charge.charge_cd in (7213,7220)
    where  FRP.renalt_chg = '1KK8888'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done by adding MAX plus GROUP BY:

```
select  
     ,FRP.rent_doc_cd as Contract
     ,max(case when charge.charge_id = 7213 then charge.chg_amt else 0 end) as FEE
     ,max(case when charge.charge_id = 7220 then charge.chg_amt  else 0 end) as Rate


FROM intgX.RENTAL_Tbl FRP                                                                 
left join intgX.RENTAL_CHG charge  on FRP.renalt_document = charge.rental_document and charge.charge_cd in (7213,7220)
where  FRP.renalt_chg = '1KK8888'
group by 1
```